# Why doesn't the div sizer container resize the video?

Tags: html, css

the div sizer doesn't resize the video on the website for some reason, can you help me with resizing this video?

```css
/* Vid*/
video {
position: relative;
top: 1400px;
right: -100px;
}
    
video:before,
video:after {
content: '';
left: 500px;
position: absolute;
}
  
.sizer {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizer">
<video src="vid1.mp4" autoplay controls></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `width: 100%` on the video, otherwise it will use the browser's default for video sizes (which is typically 300px). 100% width will force it to use the full width of its parents (in this case, set at 100px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to resize your video, you should resize the video size in html, not the div, like this

```css
/* Vid*/
video {
position: relative;
padding: 4rem;
height: 300px;
width : 600px;
}
    
video:before,
video:after {
content: '';
left: 500px;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizer">
<video src="vid1.mp4" autoplay controls></video>
</div>
```